# Perl grep not returning expected value

Tags: perl

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# splits.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $pivotfile = "myPath/Internal_Splits_Pivot.txt";

open PIVOTFILE, $pivotfile or die $!;

while (<PIVOTFILE>) { # loop through each line in file

    next if ($. == 1); # skip first line (contains business segment code)
    next if ($. == 2); # skip second line (contains transaction amount text)

    my @fields = split('\t',$_);  # split fields for line into an array     

    print scalar(grep $_, @fields), "\n"; 

}
```

Given that the data in the text file is this:

```
    4   G   I   M   N   U   X
    Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount
0000-13-I21             600         
0001-8V-034BLA              2,172   2,172       
0001-8V-191GYG                  13,125      4,375
0001-9W-GH5B2A  -2,967.09       2,967.09    25.00
```

I would expect the output from the perl script to be: `2 3 3 4` given the amount of defined elements in each line. The file is a tab delimited text file with 8 columns.

Instead I get `3 4 3 4` and I have no idea why!

For background, I am using [Counting array elements in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863426/counting-array-elements-in-perl) as the basis for my development, as I am trying to count the number of elements in the line to know if I need to skip that line or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code [works for me](http://ideone.com/DeZE2N). The problem may be that the input file contains some "hidden" whitespace fields (eg. other whitespace than tabs). For instance

- `A<tab><space><CR>` gives two fields, `A` and `<space><CR>`
- `A<tab>B<tab><CR>` gives three, `A`, `B`, `<CR>` (remember, the end of line is part of the input!)

I suggest you to `chomp` every line you use; other than that, you will have to clean the array from whitespace-only fields. Eg.

```
scalar(grep /\S/, @fields)
```

should do it.

Comment: +1 for helping me remember to `chomp`! and also for providing the answer :)

Comment: changing my answer because ultimately it was this that helped me the most! :) I posted an answer below that got the solution working for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem should be in this line:

```
my @fields = split('\t',$_);  # split fields for line into an array
```

The tab character doesn't get interpolated. And your file doesn't seem to be tab-only separated, at least here on SO. I changed the split regex to match arbitrary whitespace, ran the code on my machine and got the "right" result:

```
my @fields = split(/\s+/,$_);  # split fields for line into an array
```

Result:

```
2
3
3
4
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but no dice. I made the change, still got same results.

Comment: with `'\t'`, since `''` don't interpret backslashes except for `\\` and \', the string passed to the regex complier is actually a literal backslash and t, but the regex compiler itself handles backslashes and properly generates a tab regex.  But you are correct that /\t/ is much better form.

Comment: there do indeed have to be tabs in the original data or the results reported wouldn't occur, but I suspect /\s+/ will indeed fix the real "problem" (though it won't preserve correct information as to which data is in which tab-separated column)

Comment: @ysth the OP didn't provide any information about the structure his program tries to understand and his program just counts the splitted (true) values.

Comment: Thanks. The answer above got me there first, so I gave him the answer mark, however, I appreciate your quick reply and +1 for edit that solved the problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have spaces mixed with the tabs in some places, and your grep test will consider " " true.

What does:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;
print Dumper [<PIVOTFILE>];
```

show?

Comment: I 2nd that +1. It's been a while since I've written in perl and I forgot about this valuable resource.

Answer (score 2):

There are not only tabs, but there are spaces as well.

trying out with splitting by space works
Look below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# splits.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;



while (<DATA>) { # loop through each line in file

    next if ($. == 1); # skip first line (contains business segment code)
    next if ($. == 2); # skip second line (contains transaction amount text)


    my @fields = split(" ",$_);  # split fields by SPACE     

    print scalar(@fields), "\n"; 

}

__DATA__
    4   G   I   M   N   U   X
    Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount  Transaction Amount
0000-13-I21             600         
0001-8V-034BLA              2,172   2,172       
0001-8V-191GYG                  13,125      4,375
0001-9W-GH5B2A  -2,967.09       2,967.09    25.00
```

Output

```
2
3
3
4
```

Comment: there do indeed have to be tabs in the original data or the results reported wouldn't occur.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Since this was the first post that got to the crux of my problem, I am marking it as the answer. The issue was the extra space and changing the split to divide by spaces worked!

Comment: `split(" ",$_)` is best written as `split`

Answer (score 2):

As a side note:

> For background, I am using [Counting array elements in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863426/counting-array-elements-in-perl) as the basis for my development, as I am trying to count the number of elements in the line to know if I need to skip that line or not.

Now I understand why you use `grep` to count array elements. That's important when your array contains undefined values like here:

```
my @a;
$a[1] = 42;      # @a contains the list (undef, 42)
say scalar @a;   # 2
```

or when you manually deleted entries:

```
my @a = split /,/ => 'foo,bar';    # @a contains the list ('foo', 'bar')
delete $a[0];                      # @a contains the list (undef, 'bar')
say scalar @a;                     # 2
```

But in many cases, especially when you're using arrays to just store list without operating on single array elements, `scalar @a` works **perfectly fine**.

```
my @a = (1 .. 17, 1 .. 25);        # (1, 2, ..., 17, 1, 2, .., 25)
say scalar @a;                     # 42
```

It's important to understand, what `grep` does! In your case

```
print scalar(grep $_, @fields), "\n";
```

`grep` returns the list of **true** values of `@fields` and then you print how many you have. But sometimes this isn't what you want/expect:

```
my @things = (17, 42, 'foo', '', 0);  # even '' and 0 are things
say scalar grep $_ => @things         # 3!
```

Because the empty string and the number 0 are false values in Perl, they won't get counted with that idiom. So if you want to know how long an array is, just use

```
say scalar @array; # number of array entries
```

If you want to count **true** values, use this

```
say scalar grep $_ => @array; # number of true values
```

But if you want to count **defined** values, use this

```
say scalar grep defined($_) => @array; # number of defined values
```

I'm pretty sure you already know this from the other answers on the linked page. In hashes, the situation is a little bit more complex because setting something to `undef` is not the same as `delete`ing it:

```
my %h = (a => 0, b => 42, c => 17, d => 666);
$h{c} = undef;   # still there, but undefined
delete $h{d};    # BAM! $h{d} is gone!
```

What happens when we try to count values?

```
say scalar grep $_ => values %h;   # 1
```

because 42 is the only **true** value in `%h`.

```
say scalar grep defined $_ => values %h;   # 2
```

because 0 is defined although it's false.

```
say scalar grep exists $h{$_} => qw(a b c d);   # 3
```

because undefined values can exist. Conclusion:

**know what you're doing instead of copy'n'pasting code snippets :)**

Comment: +1 for taking the effort to write out this incredible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of great help on this question, and quickly too!

After a long, drawn-out learning process, this is what I came up with that worked quite well, with intended results.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# splits.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $pivotfile = "myPath/Internal_Splits_Pivot.txt";

open PIVOTFILE, $pivotfile or die $!;

while (<PIVOTFILE>) { # loop through each line in file

    next if ($. == 1); # skip first line (contains business segment code)
    next if ($. == 2); # skip second line (contains transaction amount text)

    chomp $_; # clean line of trailing \n and white space

    my @fields = split(/\t/,$_);  # split fields for line into an array     

    print scalar(grep $_, @fields), "\n"; 

}
```

Comment: So you still want to count *true* values only? :)

Comment: @memowe -> yes, I just want true values in the logic I am working with. I do, however, appreciate you laying out that excellent explanation. It was very clear, and helped me understand all the concepts a bit more than the original link I was working with. The generosity of SO users never ceases to amaze me!