# Array size in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to run this code and am getting output as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@array = (1,2,3);
$array[50] = 4;

$size = @array;
$max_index = $#array;

print "Size:  $size\n";
print "Max Index: $max_index\n";
```

#### Output:

```
Size: 51
Max Index: 50
```

What is the explanation for this?

Comment: What are your expectations exactly? max_index is always array_size-1.

Comment: Are you writing the code with out knowing what it is doing? Not pin pointing, but just asking you. Any how I have explained in the below answer.

Comment: @Amareesh: _I have explained in the below answer._, where?

Comment: @serenesat Oops something went wrong .. It haven't saved in below answers. But by the way I found that he has copy pasted the program which was explained very clearly in this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_arrays.htm)

Comment: @Amareesh: From where OP has copied that does not matter much. I guess OP is not able to understand so asked here for more clarification.

Comment: @serenesat I thought that user has just copy pasted some piece of code which he found in some website where it was already explained and was asking for an help. So just shared the source in comments. Any how I gave my explaination that may help him in answers. Thanks for the above.

Comment: What is there to explain? The code works as expected. What has surprised you?

Comment: @DaveCross Sir are you pointing me? just want to confirm. 
If not, I do have the same feeling which you have mentioned. Because alreday this was epxlained clearly in the source website.

Comment: My question was directed at the original poster. He said "Can you please explain this?" I was asking what he thinks we need to explain.

Comment: While the tutorialspoint link does explain this, it does so in a **horibly outdated way**. That is one of the sources of bad-written old Perl that the Perl community is trying to get rid of. Since the OP is not clarifying, let's not create a comment war here. :)

Comment: @Amit: If (as seems to be the case) your are trying to learn Perl from the terrible TutorialsPoint web site then please do yourself a favour and use something recommended on http://perl-tutorial.org/ instead.

Comment: @simbabque I totally agree with you.Tutorialspoint is horrible way to learn perl.They still don't  use  lexical filehandles and use two-arg file open syntax.

Comment: The expectation might be 4 for the size, in which case it is an exact duplicate of *[Counting elements in a sparse array in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863426/)*.

Answer (score 5):

In Perl, an array is a data structure representing a **list**. A list has **elements**. The *keys* to that list are called **indexes**. The first index is zero (`0`).

You have started your array with these indexes and values:

```
index value
0     1
1     2
2     3
```

If you set the 50th index to a value, all the other indexes in between will be filled with `undef`, the undefined value.

You have correctly identified `$#array` as the max index, or the highest or *last index*. If you [force the array into **scalar context**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html), it will give you the number of elements, or *size*. You've got that as well. And that will, as [Сухой27 said in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829130/array-size-in-perl/31829252#comment51581105_31829130), be the last index plus one.

You can illustrate that behaviour if you [dump out the array](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my @array = (1,2,3);
$array[10] = 4;

p @array;
```

It will output the following. Again you can see that the index starts at `0`, and each number between `0` and the highest index is there. So the number of elements is always one less than the last element's index.

```
[
    [0]  1,
    [1]  2,
    [2]  3,
    [3]  undef,
    [4]  undef,
    [5]  undef,
    [6]  undef,
    [7]  undef,
    [8]  undef,
    [9]  undef,
    [10] 4
]
```

---

This might be confusing if you come from a PHP background, where an array can be with indexes or [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) and still be called *array*. In Perl however those are called *hash* and they are not ordered.

I suggest you read up on how Perl data structures work in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

Answer (score 1):

The actual array which you have declared is `@array = (1,2,3);`, which means now this array has a size of *3*. Please note that always by default the index will start with `0`. So here the maximum index is `2`.

That is `$array[0] = 1, $array[1] = 2, $array[2] = 3`.

And in the next line, you are declaring *index* 50 of the above array as `4`, which means now your array will have a total of `51` values with maximum index `50`.

```
$array[50] = 4;
```

You have already declared values for index 0, 1, 2, and 50. So the remaining values will have values assigned as undefined.

`$size = @array;` - Here you are using a scalar context to get the size of an array. So you are getting output `print "Size:  $size\n";` as `51`.

`$max_index = $#array;` - Here it will display the highest index. So you are getting output print `"Max Index: $max_index\n";` as `50`.

Comment: I think you mean _highest index_ not _highest index value_.